# How to set alarm on DS3231 sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to know if it is possible to set an alarm in DS3231.
I want to set the alarm every 6 AM in the morning. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is (see datasheet [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf)) ... the DS3231 has 2 alarms.

There is also a library for the Arduino, see: [library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time).
The alarm(s) can be set (repeatedly) via one of the following functions:

```
Alarm.alarmRepeat(hours, minutes, seconds, function); 
Create an alarm that will call a function every day at a particular time. 

Alarm.alarmRepeat(dayofweek, hours, minutes, seconds, function); 
Create an alarm that will call a function every week on a specific day at     
a particular time.

 "dayofweek" can be dowSunday, dowMonday, dowTuesday, dowWednesday,
 dowThursday, dowFriday, or dowSaturday.
```

Detailed info and more functions: [link](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimeAlarms.html)

Comment: is it okay that i used the SDA SCL pins ? for ds3231 although I use the timelib.h and timealarm library?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never played with I2C so far, I see the DS3231 uses I2C, so I assume the library uses I2C to interact with the DS3231. Probably it needs to be connected via I2c (thus SDA/SCL).

Comment: When I try this ` Alarm.alarmRepeat(8,30,0, MorningAlarm);  // 8:30am every day
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(17,45,0,EveningAlarm);  // 5:45pm every day ` using the timelib.h and timerAlarm.h library , when i close the serial monitor it restart counting ..

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'restarts counting' ? I assume when the alarm(s) set is equal to the time of the IC, the alarm callback function is fired.

Comment: In the TimeAlarmExample .. 
   `setTime(9,21,0,05,03,17); // set time to Saturday 8:29:00am Jan 1 2011` time is set to 8:29 am .. and then `Alarm.alarmRepeat(8,30,0, MorningAlarm); // 8:30am every day`  when i close the serial monitor it restart counting back to 8:29 am ..

Comment: Is it possible to achieve alarm using DS3231.h library ?

Comment: I think it is, but I never tried.

Comment: But if you first set the time (to 8:29) and than the alarm (to 8:30), the time will not change; it should continue counting from the time it was set (8:29), and never reset back to 8:29 or counting backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer to my question . 
I just add `Time  t;` and `t = rtc.getTime();` into my code then an if statement like this `if (t.hour == 11 && t.min == 59 && t.sec == 00)`

ref http://www.instructables.com/id/Setup-for-DS3231-AlarmTimer-Function/

Comment: The correct way to use RTC alarms is to setup them to fire an interrupt when alarm date/time occurs. This way MCU doesn't have to poll RTC frequently. The configuration is described in "Alarms" paragraph of the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf).